# Facing challenged while creating regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I need to construct some regular expressions. I am facing issues with the listed below

1. Find all words starting with a whose letters are all in alphabetical 
   order.
   I tried - `^[a]a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o*p*q*r*s*t*u*v*w*x*y*z*$`
   but it is not working.

   **input:**

   - ab - it fails to match it
2. Find all words that contain no vowels and no y’s.
   I tried - `[^aeiouy]+$`
   but it is not working

   **input:**

   - abc - not a match
   - bc - match
   - sgpty - not a match
   - sgpt - match
3. Find all words that start with z and contain at least 2 y’s.
   I tried - `r"\b[z].*(y.*?){2}\b"`
   but it is not working properly. It matches the work but doesnot print it 
   correctly (I am simply printing match from findAll() results, nothing 
   else)

   **input:**

   - zygapophyses - match but print `yses` only
   - zygapophysis - match but print `ysis` only
4. Find all words that consist of alternating vowels and consonants (in 
   either order) and have length at least 12.
   I tried - `^(([aeiou][^aeiou])+|([^aeiou][aeiou])+)$`
   but don't know how to test the length for 12 or more characters.

   `^(([aeiou][^aeiou])+|([^aeiou][aeiou])+){12,}$` didn't work for me.

   **input:**

   - witenagemote - match
   - vituperative - match
   - vizirate - not a match
   - verisimilitude - match

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: You said, "I have created almost half of it but facing issues with the listed belows." Then show us, and share your problems. You can try by yourself at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: @Yusufsn updated.

Comment: Are you asking two questions, that is, questions about two different regular expressions?

Comment: "it is not working": *how* is it not working? what examples fail, and how do they fail? what is the input, the outcome, what did you expect? For example, your second regex could work, depending on the input.

Comment: @9769953 please check now

Comment: Your second regular expressions seems to work fine: abc and sgpty both contain vowels, and are thus not a match, while bc and sgpt do not contain any vowel, and thus match.

Comment: I can't reproduce your first example: `re.search('^[a]a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o*p*q*r*s*t*u*v*w*x*y*z*$', 'ab')` matches just fine.

Comment: @Yusufsn Can you help me on 3rd one?

Comment: @9769953 Thanks for all your help. Can you help me with 4th one I just updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one example for the 2nd question. Your regex is good enough.

```
import re
def find_word(word):
    if re.match("[^aeiouy]+$",word):
        print (word, "DOESN'T CONTAIN VOWELS OR Y")
    else:
        print (word, "CONTAINS VOWELS OR Y")

find_word("abc")
find_word("bc")
find_word("sgpty")
find_word("sgpt")
```

Output:

```
abc CONTAINS VOWELS OR Y
bc DOESN'T CONTAIN VOWELS OR Y
sgpty CONTAINS VOWELS OR Y
sgpt DOESN'T CONTAIN VOWELS OR Y
```

For the 3rd question, I also use your regex:

```
def find_z(string) : 
    regex = re.compile(r"\b[z].*(y.*?){2}\b")  
    for st in string.split():
        match_object = regex.findall(st) 
        if len(match_object) != 0 : 
            for word in match_object : 
                print(st)
        else: 
            print("Not match")
```

Output:

```
zygapophyses
zygapophysis
Not match
Not match
```

Comment: Somehow it was not working before. Since its whole word search, I had to used \b..\b

I have updated my question, can you check third one once and help me with that?

Comment: For 3rd question, I am using findAll() method and the resultant match is a string so I can't use group() function on it.


```pattern = re.compile(regex)
    for line in textfile:
        #find all matches in the current line
        linematches = pattern.findall(line)
        matches += linematches
        # if there is a match add that line with filename and line no. to lines list

    for match in matches:
        print(match)```

Comment: Thanks, it works now (I also figured out a way to capture the words). Can you help me with 4th one I just updated?

Comment: Could you provide the sample of input and the expected output as well?

Comment: updated with the input, also please find them below

input:

   - witenagemote - match
   - vituperative - match
   - vizirate - not a match
   - verisimilitude - match